# Why such huge losses in such a simple data case of Tensor Flow in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I´m trying to reproduce the example of a basic regression from Rstudio using keras in R https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/keras/regression

In my machine (Windows) the example ran fine and I get approximately the same results.

Next step, my data, just 2 parameters, very simple data

[image: variables mean and sd]

[image: distribution - correlation]

as in the code below

```
library(rsample)  # For initial_split()
library(GGally)   # For ggpairs()
library(skimr)    # For skim_with()
library(keras)    # For layer_normalization(), keras_model_sequential(), optimizer_adam()
library(dplyr)    # For select(), everything()
library(ggplot2)  # For ggplot(), geom_point(), geom_line()
library(tidyr)    # For pivot_longer()

dataset <-
  structure(list(days = c(0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 
                          70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 105, 112, 119, 126, 133, 140, 147, 154, 161, 
                          168, 175, 182, 189, 196, 203), myY = c(5533.9700000000003, 9061, 
                                                                 9509.0100000000002, 7759.3999999999996, 4436.6000000000004, 5400, 
                                                                 10626.9, 8832.9899999999998, 9496.4899999999998, 10990.9, 9495, 
                                                                 11705.99, 10892.65, 12869.9, 4410, 7318.9499999999998, 15051.540000000001, 
                                                                 10380.41, 14764.9, 5822.71, 8248.6299999999992, 9958.3700000000008, 
                                                                 10464.629999999999, 19346.959999999999, 11944.639999999999, 3906.0599999999999, 
                                                                 15991.940000000001, 12789.059999999999, 16477.82, 15121.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -30L))

tail(dataset)


split <- initial_split(dataset, 0.7)
train_dataset <- training(split)
test_dataset <- testing(split)


train_dataset %>%
  GGally::ggpairs()

skimr::skim(train_dataset)

# Split features from labels
# Separate the target value—the “label”—from the features. This label is the value that you will train the model to predict.
train_features <- train_dataset %>% select(-myY)
test_features <- test_dataset %>% select(-myY)

train_labels <- train_dataset %>% select(myY)
test_labels <- test_dataset %>% select(myY)

my_skim <- skimr::skim_with(numeric = skimr::sfl(mean, sd))
train_dataset %>%
  select(where(~is.numeric(.x))) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(values), sd = sd(values))

normalizer <- layer_normalization(axis = -1L)

normalizer %>% adapt(as.matrix(train_features))

print(normalizer$mean)

first <- as.matrix(train_features[1,])

cat('First example:', first)

cat('Normalized:', as.matrix(normalizer(first)))


days <- matrix(train_features$days)
days_normalizer <- layer_normalization(input_shape = shape(1), axis = NULL)
days_normalizer %>% adapt(days)

days_model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  days_normalizer() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

summary(days_model)

predict(days_model, days[1:10,])

days_model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(learning_rate = 0.1),
  loss = 'mean_absolute_error'
)

history <- days_model %>% fit(
  as.matrix(train_features$days),
  as.matrix(train_labels),
  epochs = 100,
  # Suppress logging.
  verbose = 0,
  # Calculate validation results on 20% of the training data.
  validation_split = 0.3
)

plot(history)

test_results <- list()
test_results[["days_model"]] <- days_model %>% evaluate(
  as.matrix(test_features$days),
  as.matrix(test_labels),
  verbose = 0
)


x <- seq(0, 300, length.out = 307)
y <- predict(days_model, x)

df2= data.frame(x=x, y=y*100)

ggplot(train_dataset) +
  geom_point(aes(x = days, y = myY, color = "data")) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x, y), aes(x = x, y = y, color = "prediction"))
```

But I got a terrible model, with very, very low target variable values, with negative values, as the prediction model returned normalized data, not in the same range as the original dataset.

[image: train validation]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?